# Why is chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished event fired hundreds of times of I don't remove them, using Preact?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension. The library I use is Preact. Here is my state and `useEffect` function.

```
const [requests, setRequests] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    function processRequest(request) {
        // if filter is unset
        if (filter == "") {
            setRequests((requests) => [...requests, request]);
        } else {
            // filter request url using wildcard
            if (request.request.url.includes(filter)) {
                setRequests((requests) => [...requests, request]);
            }
        }
    }


    chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(processRequest);

    return () => {
        
    }
}, []);
```

Then I bind `requests` to a list in html.

I build the extension, and give it a try. And I found that one refresh of the page would make the list length 20000. I know there is actually only like 40 requests. And I can see that, there are many duplicates, usually one request is saved hundreds of times.

I realized I didn't remove the event listener, so I changed the code.

```
return () => {
    chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.removeListener(processRequest);
}
```

Then it's normal.

I don't understand the mechanics of react well enough to know what's going on. Can you please explain why failing to remove the listener would cause the listener to fire hundreds of times?

Comment: A new processRequest function is created each time the callback of useEffect is executed, this is how JavaScript works, so the `chrome` API registers a new listener each time. Move processRequest to the outside scope.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` will be called every time the component renders.

The state variable change will trigger component to re-render.

Each time `useEffect` is called, it adds another eventlistener to the chrome api. Thus, causing more listener to be triggered next time a request finishes.

Listener called -> sets state variable -> componennt re-renders -> useEffect adds more listener. Then the next network request finishes, causing all the listeners to fire, then goes a new loop.

What the `useEffect` returns is a cleanup function. In this case

```
return () => {
    chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.removeListener(processRequest);
}
```

The function will be called when the components is to be unmounted, the end of lifecycle.